# Azure DevOps Maven Build PIpeline - Add build id to the Manifest File

Tags: java, azure, maven, devops

Is there a way to add the build id to the Manifest file of an EAR?
I have tried adding variables,  and I "think" I have added the Maven Options that I would normally put on the command line to set variables in my POM.  BUt nothing seems to work.

```
# Maven
# Build your Java project and run tests with Apache Maven.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/java

trigger:
- main
- dev
- qa

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  IsMasterBranch: $[ eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main') ]
  IsDevBranch: $[ eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/dev') ]
  IsQABranch: $[ eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/qa') ]
  BUILD_NUMBER: $(Build.BuildNumber)

steps:
- powershell: >
    if('$(IsMasterBranch)' -eq 'True') {
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=BuildTag;isOutput=true]$(Build.BuildId)-prod"
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=branch;isOutput=true]prod"
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=FullBuildTag;isOutput=true]$(Build.Repository.Name):$(Build.BuildId)-prod"      
    }
     elseif('$(IsDevBranch)' -eq 'True') {
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=BuildTag;isOutput=true]$(Build.BuildId)-dev"
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=branch;isOutput=true]dev"
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=FullBuildTag;isOutput=true]$(Build.Repository.Name):$(Build.BuildId)-dev"
    }
    elseif('$(IsQABranch)' -eq 'True') {
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=BuildTag;isOutput=true]$(Build.BuildId)-qa"
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=branch;isOutput=true]qa"
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=FullBuildTag;isOutput=true]$(Build.Repository.Name):$(Build.BuildId)-qa"
    }




- task: Maven@3
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
    mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    options: '-Ddevelopment_environment=$(branch) -Dbuildnumber=434'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
    goals: 'package'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/test-hello-world-app-ear/target'
    ArtifactName: 'target'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Build.BuildId** is a predefined variable and it's **the ID of the record for the completed build**. And similarly **Build.BuildNumber** is the name of the completed build, also known as the run number. You can specify [what is included](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number) in this value. A typical use of this variable is to make it part of the label format, which you specify on the repository tab.

I checked several Microsoft document and blogs but didn't found any specific way to add the build id to the Manifest file of an EAR. The only way I found is by adding the variables only. **If you are using YAML or classic build pipelines, see [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops) for a comprehensive list of system variables**.

Read this [Understand variable syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml,batch#understand-variable-syntax) to know the three different ways to reference variables.